# How to remove the query parameters from the URL once the page loads and the function that requires them goes through?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following situation:

I'm on page A which has a call button that redirects the user to page B with URL `/calls?id=1234`

On page B's `componentDidMount()`, I want to get the query parameter, use it and then remove it from the URL so that the `componentDidMount()` does not execute the function again on refresh. Right now I have the following piece of code:

```
componentDidMount() {
    const qParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.hash.split('?')?.pop());

    if (qParams.has('id')) {
        this.initiateCall(new DiallerRoomUser(
            DiallerRoomUserType.matrix,
            getLocalUserIdFromUserId(qParams.get('id')),
        ));
        qParams.delete('id');
        const url = new URL(window.location);
        url.hash = '#/calls';
        window.history.pushState({}, '', url);
    }
}
```

The URL I'm working with looks like this:

```
https://127.0.0.1:8080/#/calls?id=test
```

I believe I gotta use history.pushState but what happens with my code right now is the following:

- I click the button on page A that redirects me to page B.
- I get to page B and the `componentDidMount()` code executes correctly
  BUT the URL doesn't change.
- I refresh the page once, `componentDidMount()` code executes again but
  this time the URL changes to the correct one.

Comment: Why do not you use react-router?

Comment: what does "click the button on page A" do ? A `history.pushState` ? with wich url ?